# Реализация системы динамических приоритетов. Java

Tags: java, динамические-массивы

В данный момент пытаюсь разобраться с внедрением динамических приоритетов в свой проект.

У меня есть объект, условно назовем его `Request`. У объекта есть время последнего вызова (`long timeLast`) и периодичность вызова (`double period`). Приоритет вычисляется по формуле - `(currentTime(нынешнее время) - timeLast)/period`.

Я создаю `ArrayList` таких объектов. Мне необходимо в каждый момент времени получать актуальный приоритет и в зависимости от приоритета производить сортировку этого `ArrayList` (сортировка реализована компаратором, там все окей). Каким образом я мог бы это реализовать, если честно - просто нет идей на этот счет. Знаю о существовании алгоритма EDF, но найти его реализацию в просторах интернета так и не удалось.
Спасибо большое.

Comment: Не понятно зачем это?

Comment: Ну вы можете использовать любой таймер и сделать это в лоб. Или данный вариант слишком систему награждает?

Comment: В лоб каким образом? Я если честно не совсем понимаю как к этому подступиться. Нужно это для контролирования процессов во времени. У какого процесса сейчас приоритет выше - тот и выполняется, причем после выполнения приоритет процесса обнуляется. Причем выполняются процессы примерно каждые 16мс.

Comment: А может проще сделать очередь выполнения (с учетом времени) и просто добавлять в нее таски? Ибо зачем пересчитывать так часто у всех приоритеты, если изменяются они на самом деле только при вызове?

Comment: Riĥard Brugekĥaim, ого, интересный вариант, попробую реализовать. Спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите на `java.util.PriorityQueue`.